# Rails 4 - change URL from /user/:id to /:username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a controller pages#dashboard that I have set to be the user_root in my *routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
devise_scope :user do
  get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new"
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "/:id" => "users#dashboard", :as => "user_root", :id => :username
end
```

I want the URL to be http://my_app.com/current_user_username

I have set the to_param in the *user.rb* model to:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

This works fine when I have a link such as:

```
<%= link_to "MY ACCOUNT", user_root_path(current_user) %>
```

But on initial login, the URL is: http://my_app.com/username (explicitly says 'username') instead of http://my_app.com/current_user_username

I have tried setting my to_param to:

```
def to_param
  "#{username}"
end
```

and have also tried setting my *route.rb* to:

```
get "/:id" => "users#dashboard", :as => "user_root", :id => :username, :via => :get
```

Neither of these have solved the issue.

Environment: Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.3.0, Devise gem 3.5.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your controller instead of using `User.find(params[:id])`  you now need to use `User.find_by_username(params[:id])`. You can also checkout  [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding this to *application_controller.rb*

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_root_path(current_user)
end
```

** This is a Devise specific answer.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add another route above everything in your routes.rb as:

```
get "/:username" => "users#dashboard", :as => "user_root"
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
devise_scope :user do
  get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new"
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "/:id" => "users#dashboard", :as => "user_root", :id => :username
end
```

Then you need to find the user by something like this:

```
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id):

```
#Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'

$ rails generate friendly_id #-> generates initializer
$ rails generate scaffold user name:string slug:string:uniq #-> adds slug column
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will allow you to use the `slug` / `username` in lieu of the primary key:

```
<%= link_to current_user.username, user_path(current_user) #-> <a href="/users/john_jones" %>
```

You would not have to change your controller code etc for this to work.

--

Your routes can be simplified:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :user, path: "", only: :show #-> url.com/:id to users#show
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }, path_names: { sign_in: "login", password: "forgot", confirmation: "confirm", unlock: "unblock", sign_up: "", registration: "signup", sign_out: "logout" }
```

Whilst I don't know if you can use `current_user` inside your routes (I'm sure you can but I've not tested), you may wish to use `/profile` like this:

```
resource :profile, controller: :users, only: :show
```

This will send `url.com/profile` to the `users#show` action:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      current_user...
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and made a few changes to routes and it worked here are the sets to do:

1. under User.rb model
   def to_param
   username
   end
2. Routes:
   resources :users, :path => '/' do
   end
3. Controllers
   @user=User.find_by_username(params[:id])
4. Views
   link_to @user.username, @user.username.
   Avoid user_path because it would redirect you to [www.example.com/users/david](http://www.example.com/users/david)
   instead follow up this i have noted above
   it will [www.example.com/david](http://www.example.com/david) this is better than the first.

hope anyone would be helped.